# Moving all keyframes forward/backwards in time, including bones?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have an animation set up, which includes LocRot keyframes for bones (using the Pose mode). I want to tweak individual timing of events in my animation by moving all keyframes after a certain point forward or backwards in time.

For all regular objects, I found this can be done with the dope sheet - select all objects, then brush over all keyframes in the dopesheet (in summary view), and move them left or right.

However, this does not seem to apply to bones/pose transforms -- when I highlight all objects, the keyframes for the bone transformations are not visible on the dope sheet, and thus can't be moved along with the rest.

How can I move keyframes of both regular objects and pose transforms with a single operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dopesheet is your friend, just check the settings of its two visibility buttons, one will let you edit only selected objects, the other will let you edit hidden objects also.

In my example, editing will affect the cube as object, the armature as bone keyframed in pose mode, and a hidden bezier curve (again as object).

[image]

Comment: Indeed - this is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you have also been using the NLA you will need to move them separately to the dope sheet action moves.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.